# Ampersand and mixins in SCSS

Tags: sass, mixins

Searched but can't find an answer..

I have an element which gets generated (by an external platform) with the following classes: p-button and button.

Now the SCSS is like this:

```
.p-button {
    &.button {
        margin: 10px;
    }
 }
```

But I want to refactor using mixin includes (this is a big project so there is no other way of making this code better except using mixins). The mixin takes the given selector and applies a . to it. I can't change the mixin, as it is used by many other teams, so I can't pass the ampersand together with the selector. I tried this:

```
.p-button {
    & {
        @include button-appearance("button") {
           margin: 10px;
        }
    }
 }
```

But that doesn't work (puts a space between it). You can't do this:

```
.p-button {
    &@include button-appearance("button") {
        margin: 10px;
    }
 }
```

Anyone have a clue?

**EDIT: Here is the mixin**

```
@mixin button-appearance(
    $appearance-class, 
    $show, 
    $background-color, 
    $background-image, 
    $background-position) { 
        $sel: $button-selector;
           @if $appearance-class {
                $sel: $sel + '.' + $appearance-class;
         }

#{$sel} {
    @include normalized-background-image($background-image);
    @include show($show);
    background-color: $background-color;
    background-position: $background-position;
    }

    @content;
}
```

**EDIT 2: Here is the $button-selector (I can not edit this in the platform, but maybe overwrite it in my own project?)**

```
$button-class: 'p-button';

$button-selector: '.#{$button-class}';
```

Comment: Are you simply wanting to inherit the styles for the `.button` class for `.p-button` selector?

Comment: @R-b-n can you add to your question the value of `$button-selector`?

Comment: Thanks for looking, just did!

Comment: @R-b-n seems like you will never be able to insert content to the selector using the mixin. The ‘@content’ keyword is outside the generated selector. So you should do that using a simple selector.

Comment: @R-b-n check my edited answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone, finally found the solution. I just removed the &.button from the .p-button mixin include and now it works:

```
@include button-appearance ("button") { *styles* }
@include button-appearance () { *styles* }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited the answer after the original question was edited adding the used and un modifiable mixin**

The original mixin does not append the ‘@content’ passed to the mixin to the generated selector. So if you cannot modify the original mixin, the only way is to add your properties outside the mixin. According to the mixin the selector will match a predefined ‘$button-selector’ variable, so it won’t use your class.

So, if you want to use the same class defined in ‘$button-class’, try the following:

```
#{$button-selector}.button {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Will output:

```
.p-button.button {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: OP said they can't change the mixin.

Comment: @Arkellys can you add to your question the value of ‘$button-selector’?

Comment: I am not sure to understand?

Comment: @Arkellys the mixin you are using, uses a variable to define the base selector name `$sel: $button-selector;`; `$button-selector` is a variables and is not defined in the scope of the mixin and isn't defined as a mixin parameter. So the variable is define outside the mixin.

Comment: Ohh I think you are confusing me with OP, you should post this comment on the question. :)